# Can one dynamically insert ng-repeats into an angular app

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, view, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

`ng-repeat` is very useful, however I am finding my application needing dynamic insertion of `ng-repeats`

Is it possible to insert html dynamically into the view from one of the javascript controllers?

Alright; my specific use-case is the following:

I have a nested `ng-repeat` in my view:

```
<div id="sunti_grid">
        <div class="sunti_contain" ng-repeat="sunti in showable_suntis track by $index">
            <div class="individual_sunti" ng-click="descendents(sunti.short_id); update_ancestor(sunti);" ng-dblclick="update_ancestor(null);" ng-class="{active_sunti : actively_selected_sunti == sunti.short_id}">
                <div class="sunti_content" ng-bind="sunti.content"></div>
                <div class="sunti_tags" ng-bind="sunti.tags"></div>
                <div class="sunti_author" ng-bind="sunti.author"></div>
                <div class="sunti_shortid" ng-bind="sunti.short_id"></div>
                <div class="sunti_ancestor" ng-bind="sunti.ancestor"></div>
                <div class='rating_contain' ng-show="is_user_authenticated">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sunti_reply_carriage_wrapper" ng-if="descendents(sunti.short_id).length > 0">
                <div class="sunti_reply_carriage">
                    <div class="individual_sunti reply_carriage_sunti" ng-repeat="descendent in descendents(sunti.short_id)">
                        <div class="sunti_content" ng-bind="descendent.content"></div>
                        <div class="sunti_tags" ng-bind="descendent.tags"></div>
                        <div class="sunti_author" ng-bind="descendent.author"></div>
                        <div class="sunti_shortid" ng-bind="descendent.short_id"></div>
                        <div class='rating_contain' ng-show="is_user_authenticated">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So basically, `sunti_grid` has an ng-repeat that makes a long list of *suntis* and each *sunti* can have descendents.  The descendents appear in a "carriage" that manifests immediately below the given *sunti*.

Now, when a user clicks on a descendent (kinda like a magically-appearing row-drop-down) I want to inject yet another carriage.

Here is a simple schematic to illustrate the feature so far:

```
          [sunti]
           [sunti]
          [sunti]
       [d][d][d][d][d]..
           [sunti]
           [sunti]
        [d][d][d][d][d][d]...
```

Now I want to be able to inject another carriage of descendents for each descendent-row.. kinda like

```
           [sunti]
           [sunti]
        [d][D][d][d][d][d]...
           [D2][D2][D2][D2]...
               [D3][D3][D3]...
```

so clicking on [D] would make the [D2] row appear, and clicking on one of the [D2]s would make row [D3] appear...

The only thing I can think of so far is to use the controller to inject a new ng-repeat for every new descendent row.

Suggestions welcome.  What would be a good (read: maintainable) way of dynamically inserting ngRepeats?

Comment: Numerous ways to do it but best approach would depend on use case. Please provide more specific details about your need. A controller should never be involved in manipulating the dom

Comment: can do this in a recursive template with `ng-if`. Need all the nesting to have same structure at each level. Use click event to toggle the boolean for the `ng-if`

Comment: @charlietfl 'recursive template'  thank you very much for the keyword.  If you'd like to post your solution as an answer I would happily accept it; this gives me plenty to work off of.